# Getting all rows from a oracle table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Suppose a oracle table has many rows. How can i fetch specific column for all rows?
Let, in a table named teacher_description, there are 100 rows with columns teacher_id,teacher_name. How can i get the teacher_id for 100 rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select teacher_id  from teacher_description
```

Comment: it will return all record of id

Comment: getting this error:: Error(1090,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: what result was given?

Answer (score 0):

As `Ashish Pandya` said, you can use just a simple select.

If you get `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement` error, I think you are calling this statement inside a code block; in this case you need to get the result in a cursor.

Take a look on the following code:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare   
  cursor v_cursor is select teacher_id from teacher_description;
begin

  for idx in v_cursor loop
    dbms_output.put_line(idx.teacher_id);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If you need to understand the cursors you can find here a fast link, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm, but I suggest you start reading here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html.